# Query a table and sum datas depending their status

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure:

Table `___BillableDatas`:

```
|--------|---------------|------------|----------|--------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | BIL_Status |
|--------|---------------|------------|----------|--------------|------------|
| 1      | 21            | 2017-12-23 | 10.00    | 2            | charged    |
| 2      | 21            | 2017-12-23 | 105.00   | 1            | charged    |
| 3      | 21            | 2017-12-24 | 105.00   | 1            | charged    |
| 4      | 21            | 2017-12-25 | 105.00   | 1            | notcharged |
| 5      | 21            | 2017-12-26 | 105.00   | 1            | notcharged |
| 6      | 21            | 2017-12-26 | 30.00    | 2            | charged |
|--------|---------------|------------|----------|--------------|------------|
```

I would like to have an `array` showing the total of items per day depending on the status `charged` and `notcharged`.

The desired output should be the following:

```
Array
(
    [2017-12-23] => Array
        (
            [charged] => 125.00
            [notcharged] => 0.00
        )
    [2017-12-24] => Array
        (
            [charged] => 105.00
            [notcharged] => 0.00
        )
    [2017-12-25] => Array
        (
            [charged] => 0.00
            [notcharged] => 105.00
        )
    [2017-12-26] => Array
        (
            [charged] => 30.00
            [notcharged] => 105.00
        )
)
```

The query I tried:

```
select a.BIL_BookingId,a.BIL_Date,a.BIL_Rate*a.BIL_Quantity as total, a. BIL_Status
from ___BillableDatas as a
```

Comment: Please define 'total of things'.

Comment: Hello @KIKOSoftware, it should be `items`.

Comment: Please add the tag of the language your are using to build the array.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: it's now done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use sum and group by  (and if null for get 0 when null)

```
select BIL_Date, 
  ifnull(sum(case when BIL_Status ='charged' then BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) as charged,
  ifnull(sum(case when BIL_Status ='notcharged' then BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) as notcharged
from ___BillableDatas
group by BIL_Date
```

Comment: Hello, how can I make the date become the index of each array like in my example please ?

Comment: Mysql return a relation and not a nested  structure. If you need  a nested 
 result you must build the array server side  ... but remember that the result of the query is more simple  .. you don't need  the nested  array for charged  and not charged .. you all the result  on the same row ..  so you can manage witha simple loop ..

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally sum, check the grouping:

```
select a.BIL_BookingId
      ,a.BIL_Date
      ,CASE WHEN BIL_Status = 'charged' THEN a.BIL_Rate*a.BIL_Quantity ELSE 0 END as charged
      ,CASE WHEN BIL_Status = 'notcharged' THEN a.BIL_Rate*a.BIL_Quantity ELSE 0 END as notcharged
  from ___BillableDatas as a
  group by a.BIL_BookingId, a.BIL_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return one row per date:

```
select
    BIL_Date,
    sum((BIL_Status = 'charged')    * BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) as charged,
    sum((BIL_Status = 'notcharged') * BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) as notcharged
from ___BillableDatas
where BIL_BookingId = 21
group by BIL_Date
```

Since `BookingId` isn't in your result array, I assume that you only need data for a specific `BookingId`, which is defined in the WHERE clause.

Note that an expression like `(BIL_Status = 'charged')` will return `1` for TRUE or `0` for FALSE in MySQL. This way you can avoid long CASE statements. There is also no need for `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()`, since there will always be at least one row with a non NULL value for the `SUM()`.

After executing the query in PHP you can build the nested array in one loop while fetching the data:

```
$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['BIL_Date']] = [
        'charged'    => $row['charged'],
        'notcharged' => $row['notcharged']
    ];
}
```